When I use rigid body collision, if the volume is too large, it will cause decoupling
When I use rigid body collision, if the volume is too large, it will cause decoupling. Not having a large volume would not lead to this situation.Can you help me take a look at this issue？thanks!



Well, that "love" for my answer did not last very long. If this does not solve your issue, please clarify what is still problematic?

A quick solution might be to increase the Substeps per Frames and the Solver Iterations in the under Rigid Body World > Settings in the Scene Properties.
But I usually don't go much higher than 20 substeps and 50 iterations. Increasing these values will make the simulations more precise and stable, but they also take longer to be simulated. But even if you have a powerful computer I would not go much higher with the substeps, because there comes a point when the simulation gets seemingly worse again, so it is not necessarily the more, the better.

This would be my answer on how to improve your current simulation.
However, another method which I nowadays prefer is the (relatively new) Compund Parent in rigid body physics. It does not use the exact meshes for the chain links, but it is much quicker to simulate and much more stable.
Maybe I'll give a quick overview when I have more time later, but actually you should learn this with a real tutorial, I haven't seen many explaining the Compound Parent yet, but here is one for a chain:
Blender: Rigid Body and Compound Parent
